# Aliasing a constrained association

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm in the process of porting an existing web application from PHP to Node and using Sequelize to describe the existing data tables.  The port will be done in phases so its not going to be possible to adapt to Sequelize's preferred naming conventions or table arrangements, but I believe the existing table definitions can be adequately described, plus there is always Sequelize's raw query capabilities if I get stuck.

One of the tables has an association via a through table.  `venues` is required to have an attribute `regions` which is an array of tags that belong to the `region` category and are associated to the venue instance.

- The through table is `venue_relatesto_tags`
- `venue.id` matches `venue_relatesto_tags.venue_id`
- `venue_relatesto_tags.tag_id` matches `tags.id`
- `tags.category_id` matches `tag_categories.id`
- `tag_category.category` contains a string such as `region`

Existing PHP:

```php
public static function findOneByVenueWithCategory(PDO $pdo, Venue $venue, $category) {
        $sql = '    SELECT tags.* FROM venue_relatesto_tags
                    JOIN tags on venue_relatesto_tags.tag_id = tags.id
                    JOIN tag_categories on tag_categories.id = tags.tag_category_id
                    WHERE venue_relatesto_tags.venue_id = :venue_id
                        AND tag_categories.category = :category
                    LIMIT 1';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindParam(':venue_id', $venue->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $s->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        return self::findOneByStatement($pdo, $s, 'Tag');
    }
```

NB: I'm aware that in this case its getting only one tag, which is actually a bug in the existing application, the relationship properly supports N venues with M tags via the through table, and in other parts of the application, multiple tags are returned for particular tag categories.

In the example I'm working on, I have a 'venue' table, which is tagged to belong to one or more 'regions'.

NB: The table defs here are truncated for clarity:

[schema fragment]

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `tag_categories`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tag_categories`;
CREATE TABLE `tag_categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `singular` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plural` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `tags`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tags`;
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tag_category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `venues`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `venues`;
CREATE TABLE `venues` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=194 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used `sequelize-auto` to generate the sequelize `defines, with the addition of muting the timestamps.

[venues]

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('venues', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    // ...
  }, {
    tableName: 'venues',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

[venues_relatesto_tags]

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('venue_relatesto_tags', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    venue_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true
    },
    tag_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'venue_relatesto_tags',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

[tags]

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('tags', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    tag_category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'tags',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

[tag_categories]

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('tag_categories', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    category: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
      allowNull: false
    },
    // ...
  }, {
    tableName: 'tag_categories',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

```js
function associateSchema(db) {
  db.models.venues.belongsToMany(db.models.tags, {
    through: 'venue_relatesto_tags',
    foreignKey: 'venue_id',
    otherKey: 'tag_id',
    as: 'tags'
  })
  // This association is what I current have to get an appropriate
  // alias to the region tags
  db.models.venues.belongsToMany(db.models.tags, {
    through: 'venue_relatesto_tags',
    foreignKey: 'venue_id',
    otherKey: 'tag_id',
    as: 'regions'
  })
  db.models.tags.belongsTo(db.models.tag_categories, {
    foreignKey: 'tag_category_id',
    as: 'categories'
  })
  // other associations...
  db.sync({ alter: false })
}
```

I then have the following scope defined:

```js
function addScopes(db) {
  db.models.events.addScope('defaultScope', {
    include: [
      {
        association: 'venue',
        include: [
          {
            association: 'regions',
            include: [
              {
                association: 'categories',
                attributes: [], // don't need the categories in the result
                where: {
                  // only get region tags
                  category: 'region'
                }
              }
            ],
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
    order: [ 'title' ]
  }, {
    override: true
  })
}
```

That works, in that I end up with an array of 'regions' in my venue instance.  `include` has an `as` option but appears to only work with `model`, so the duplicate association (`tags`/`regions`) seems to be the only way to describe this, which doesn't seem very DRY (not to mention potentially confusing from a maintenance perspective).

This `venue` table only has this one region tag association, but other tables have multiple associations all based on tags but for different categories, so I can see that I'm going to run into this again and again, and its a bad code smell.

As far as I can see there is no difference to me using Scopes versus options to the query methods, and I can see that I might choose to have multiple scopes so that I don't generate more join's than necessary when I don't need the data (or use overrides to limit the default scope).

I'm sure someone might argue that the existing table structure is not ideal, its legacy, I need to accommodate its foibles without carrying them over lock, stock and barrel to the new implementation.  Once the legacy code is out of the way, there will be an opportunity to refactor the table structure.

So far I've not seen a need to describe the inverse relationship, but that may be because I'm only scratching the surface so far and evaluating whether Sequelize will fit my needs.  One option is to use a raw MYSQL driver and merely replicate the queries from the PHP application, but one aspect of that is that the PHP application was not necessarily optimal in its SQL implementation.

Comment: Hello, I will see if I can try to help, but I found your question hard to follow. I am sure that porting legacy code to another language is a pain, but I commend your goal, it is surely a great thing to move from PHP to NodeJS with Sequelize. I am pretty sure it can be done. I've also just seen the issue you opened (#10474), I will try to help.

Comment: In the meantime, can you try to edit your question, perhaps explain in other words how are your tables currently structured, I found it hard to follow. You talk about 1:M relationships with a through table, but that doesn't make sense. Through tables only make sense for N:M relationships. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroA Thanks, question edited, and yes, I was off by describing them as 1:M, they should be N:M.  Sorry, long time since I had to maintain this app and use relational terminology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have three tables: `venues`, `tags` and `tag_categories`. Also, there is a N:M relation between `venues` and `tags` which is handled by the through table (also sometimes called junction table or joint table) `venue_relatesto_tags`. There is also a 1:N relation between `tag_categories` and `tags` (meaning that every tag has one category, and the same category can be applied to many tags).

You want to query **only the venues which have at least one tag whose category is `"region"`**, and also you want each obtained venue object to have an extra field `"regions"` which is an array of tags containing only this venue's tags whose category is `"region"`.

#### Model definitions

To run my own code, I will be using sequelize with a local postgres database for tests.

For completeness, the models I will be using are below. They are the same as yours, but I omitted the `id` fields and added a `references` field where applicable. My whole code will be in one file, but you can keep your one-table-per-file setup.

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/testdb", { dialect: "postgres" });

const Venue = sequelize.define('venues', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING(255)
}, { tableName: 'venues', timestamps: false });

const Tag = sequelize.define('tags', {
    description: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    tag_category_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        references: { model: "tag_categories", key: "id" }
    }
}, { tableName: 'tags', timestamps: false });

const TagCategory = sequelize.define('tag_categories', {
    category: Sequelize.STRING(64)
}, { tableName: 'tag_categories', timestamps: false });

const Venue_Tag = sequelize.define('venue_relatesto_tags', {
    venue_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        references: { model: "venues", key: "id" }
    },
    tag_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        references: { model: "tags", key: "id" }
    }
}, { tableName: 'venue_relatesto_tags', timestamps: false });
```

#### Relations

You set up some complicated relations between the tables, using aliases. The worst of it was creating two belongs-to-many relations between the same models, with different aliases. I understand why you tried that, based on your goal, but that's very confusing to say the least. So I won't do that. The solution for getting the fields you want will be different: instead of trying to make sequelize itself produce the exact structure you want with the field names you want, we will just get the data with sequelize and conform them later with pure JavaScript.

```js
Venue.belongsToMany(Tag, { through: Venue_Tag, foreignKey: 'venue_id', otherKey: 'tag_id' });
Tag.belongsToMany(Venue, { through: Venue_Tag, foreignKey: 'tag_id', otherKey: 'venue_id' });
TagCategory.hasMany(Tag, { foreignKey: 'tag_category_id' });
Tag.belongsTo(TagCategory, { foreignKey: 'tag_category_id' });
```

#### Populating the database with test values

This part is here for completeness only, to show you how I have populated my own database with dummy values, to test my own code. I decided to create two different `tag_categories`, one of them called `"Region"`. Also, I created four tags, two of them categorized as `"Region"`, and two `venues`, the first with all tags and the second without the region-categorized tags. See below.

```js
function setup() {
  return sequelize.sync({ force: true })
    .then(() => Promise.all([
        TagCategory.create({ category: "Region" }),
        TagCategory.create({ category: "Other Category" })
    ]))
    .spread((region, otherCategory) => Promise.all([
        Tag.create({ description: "Tag 1", tag_category_id: otherCategory.id }),
        Tag.create({ description: "Tag 2", tag_category_id: otherCategory.id }),
        Tag.create({ description: "Tag 3", tag_category_id: region.id }),
        Tag.create({ description: "Tag 4", tag_category_id: region.id })
    ]))
    .spread((tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4) => Promise.all([
        Venue.create({ title: "Venue 1" }).tap(venue => venue.setTags([tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4])),
        Venue.create({ title: "Venue 2" }).tap(venue => venue.setTags([tag1, tag2]))
    ]));
}
```

#### The query

The following query gets all venues which have at least one tag categorized as `"Reason"`, including only these tags:

```js
Venue.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tag,
    required: true,
    include: {
      model: TagCategory,
      required: true,
      where: {
        category: "Region"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

#### Formatting it for the desired structure

You said that you want the field containing these tags to be named `regions`, so we just fix that with JavaScript. We may also delete the fields `"venue_relatesto_tags"` and `tag_category` which I guess that aren't desired. Code:

```js
setup()
    .then(() => Venue.findAll({
        include: {
            model: Tag,
            required: true,
            include: {
                model: TagCategory,
                required: true,
                where: {
                    category: "Region"
                }
            }
        }
    }))
    .then(venues => {
        venues = venues.map(venue => venue.toJSON());
        for (const venue of venues) {
            venue.regions = venue.tags;
            delete venue.tags;
            for (const tag of venue.regions) {
                delete tag.venue_relatesto_tags;
                delete tag.tag_category;
            }
        }
        return venues;
    })
    .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)))
    .finally(() => sequelize.close());
```

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Venue 1",
    "regions": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "description": "Tag 4",
        "tag_category_id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "Tag 3",
        "tag_category_id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Preserving sequelize instances

The code above converts the query result to pure JSON in order to freely manipulate its fields. If you still need the sequelize instances, another option is to use a pseudo-field called `"regions"` in your Venue model. Change your model to the following:

```js
const Venue = sequelize.define('venues', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING(255)
}, {
    tableName: 'venues',
    timestamps: false,
    getterMethods: {
        regions() {
            if (!this.tags) return;
            if (this.tags.length === 0) return [];
            if (!this.tags[0].tag_category) return;
            return this.tags.filter(tag => tag.tag_category.category === 'Region');
        }
    }
});
```

Also, for better organization, I suggest creating a scope for it (as you already wanted since the beginning):

```js
Venue.addScope('findWithRegions', {
    include: {
        model: Tag,
        required: true,
        include: {
            model: TagCategory,
            required: true,
            where: {
                category: 'Region'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The query will now become:

```js
setup()
    .then(() => Venue.scope("findWithRegions").findAll())
    .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)))
    .finally(() => sequelize.close());
```

#### Final thoughts

Although I gave you above an option of using a pseudo-field, so that you can have the field you want without losing the sequelize instance, I think you should rethink why exactly you need it this way. It does not make sense to me to need both things at the same time. Sequelize is meant to communicate with the database and retrieve data as objects in a way that intuitively maps to the entries in the database. On the other hand, the fact that you want an extra field with a different name seems more like a front-end requirement or something else that is not in the same "abstraction layer" as the ORM. I think you should try to organize your code in a way that you can make all the queries you want with sequelize, in the sense of grabbing the data you need, but you should "conform" them to whichever structure you need only on another step. And, in that step, you shouldn't need the sequelize instance anymore. To make things organized, you could perhaps create a helper method in your Venue model:

```js
Venue.prototype.toJSONWithRegions = function() {
    const asJSON = this.toJSON();
    asJSON.regions = asJSON.tags;
    delete asJSON.tags;
    for (const tag of asJSON.regions) {
        delete tag.venue_relatesto_tags;
        delete tag.tag_category;
    }
    return asJSON;
};

// call it as follows:
// const myVenueAsJSON = myVenueSequelizeInstance.toJSONWithRegions();
```

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks, all correct except your last para, which is true, but also when I query venues, each venue instance should have an attribute ‘regions’, an array of tags that are in the region category, specific to that venue (usually only one, but can be more than one).

Comment: @DaveMeehan - I've edited the answer. Let me know if I got it right.

Comment: Yes that’s the correct shape. If in place of ‘tags’ you used ‘facilities’, that might better reflect how tag categories are used (tags might be ‘parking’, ‘accessible’, ‘refreshments’).

Comment: @DaveMeehan - Ok! I will work out some code and edit my answer soon.

Comment: @DaveMeehan - I've completed the answer, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it’ll be much later today or tomorrow before I get to try this, I’ll cone back with what I find.

Comment: Thanks again, got to look at that sooner than expected and that's really helped.  There are a couple of things I don't understand, such as putting the `references` in the `define`s, as I mentioned, I used sequelize-auto to read the existing table definitions so don't have the opportunity to modify those and keep a workflow of auto generation should the legacy tables receive definition updates (not expected, but not impossible).

Comment: The 'secret sauce' was making a transform on the result to convert the tags to categorised attributes.  Is there a way of applying a hook to results, I can't find one mentioned in the docs?

Comment: There is a problem that I see here, which is that transforming the result strips of the Sequelize instance by converting it to a plain object.  I've not delved into custom getters to know if this is an alternative way of handling the transform (i.e. an attribute called `regions` which returns only tags on the instance that belong to the region category).

Comment: @DaveMeehan Indeed the code I wrote strips the sequelize instance, but it is possible to do it without that happening. I will edit my code soon. As for the hook you asked, I don't think there is exactly a hook but I will suggest something similar soon. About the `references` field, don't worry about it.